# Execute a command after `git push` finalize, using git hook

Tags: git, hook

I was trying to run a command after `git push` is finalized but it doesn't run
I try with `post-receive`, `post-update` and `pre-push`
worked with pre-push

**Some info:**
git version 2.17.1
path files: testProject/.git/hooks/
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

**Example of code:**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to prepare a packed repository for use over
# dumb transports.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-update".

echo "test" > /home/Darck/Desktop/testProject/test.txt
# exec git update-server-info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[post-receive/update](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) are [server-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks), so if you have defined them locally (on where you are doing the push), they would not run anyway.

The [pre-push hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_other_client_hooks) should run, provided it has been defined in your own repo, and made executable, in `myrepo/.git/hooks/pre-push`